# Запятая при обороте "такой же, как"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, обороты-с-как

> К Александру подошел человек **в таком же как на мне военном
> ватнике**, с продолговатым баулом в руке, и спросил...

Виктор Пелевин, "Священная книга оборотня"

Есть ли такие случаи, когда запятая в конструкции "такой же, как" не ставится, и если да, то какие?

Comment: Интересный вопрос, Иван. Хотела уже сказать, что так нельзя, никто так не делает, а потом задумалась. А вдруг все-таки можно? Пока думаю...))

Comment: @Sharon А вы подумайте, подумайте, хорошенько только. Может быть, это очередная авторская?))

Comment: Очередная? Впрочем, авторское решение нужно отличать от факультативного выбора, разрешенного правилами. А если правило до конца не продумано, а писатель это видит. Это как в математике,  когда названы не все возможные решения)  Вы же, мне думается, любите стабильную однозначность более всего)  А вот для меня теория виртуальных множеств более привлекательна. Хотя консервативное большинство уверено не все сто, как Иван Бездомный у Булгакова: оборот, конечно же. обособляется,  И если уж очевидное трудно отстоять, то здесь задача посложнее. Стоит ли рисковать) Возьмутся за меня всерьез...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Правило: ПАС по ред Лопатина,** **[§ 88](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125#pp125)**

**Примечание**. Если союз КАК и указательные слова ТАК, ТАКОЙ  с частицей ЖЕ оказываются рядом, то они могут сливаться **в единое союзное сочетание:** Он, так же как Ильюшин, учился в Военно-воздушной академии (А. Яковлев).

**2. [Справочник по пунктуации](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_722)**

Однако в некоторых случаях запятая ставится не перед словом «как», а перед словом «такой»:

(1) если слова «такой как» соотносятся с предшествующим прилагательным: **Погода дождливая, такая как осенью.** Обстановка в этом доме была **мрачная, такая как** в старинных замках (ср.: Погода такая, как осенью. Обстановка в этом доме была такая, как в старинных замках);

**РЕШЕНИЕ**

**Вариант 1. Какой был ватник?**

Ватник был (1) **военный,** (2) такой же  (3) как на мне.

Три определения: прилагательное +  (местоимение и сравнительный оборот).

***Такой же как на мне*** — единое  сочетание о значением **уточнения**.

**Вариант 2. В каком он был ватнике?**

Все напишут **так** (потому что **они все)**:

*Он  был (1) в таком же, / (2) **как на мне**, (3) / военном ватнике.*

Три определения: местоимение + сравнительный оборот + прилагательное. **Перечисление** трех определений?

**А почему не так?**

*Он был в таком же как на мне, / **военном**, / вАтнике.* Это **пояснение**.

**Или так**:

*Он был **в таком же как на мнЕ**, воЕнном ватнике.* Это **однородные** отношения при пояснении (по Розенталю).

**Или так**:

*Он был **в таком же как на мне / военном** вАтнике.* Это **неоднородные** отношения.

При выборе надо учитывать грамматику **конкретного** предложения.

**ВЫВОД**

**Пушкин сказал:** "*Поэт **сам избирает** предметы для своих песен; толпа не имеет права управлять его вдохновением"*.

А я добавлю: *Писатель **сам выбирает** форму записи для своего текста.*

**Правильно:**

*К Александру подошел человек **в таком же как на мне /  военном** вАтнике, // с продолговатым баУлом в руке, // и спросил...*

Comment: A как однородные отношения в предпоследнем примере стали неоднородными в последнем? Что указывает на это?

Comment: Это были пояснительные однородные отношения. (1) У него был такОй же, воЕнный ватник.  (2) У него был такой же военный вАтник. Вы различаете эти варианты? Как выбираете?  // Нападение – это лучшая защита))

Comment: Что вы, что вы, я и не думал нападать.) Просто чтобы разбираться в таких тонких нюансах, надо закончить курсы интонационно-выразительного чтения. В противном же случае можно минут 30 думать над одним предложением, какие именно смысловые отношения в него вкладывал автор, ушедший в сторону от нормативного регулирования.)

Comment: Это я нападаю))  Я такая хитрая рыжая лисичка, совсем как в вашей книге.   Мне хочется больше узнать о вас. Значит, интонационно-выразительное чтение? Так вы оцениваете интонационный принцип в пунктуации?  Тогда я задам на форуме вопрос (со своим ответом) на тему интонации. И надеюсь, что после этого  вы немедленно приступите к изучению интонационно-выразительного чтения. А все остальное пока отложите в сторону))  Идет?

Comment: Да я только за! Конечно же, новые знания, что может быть лучше?!)

Answer (score 1):

**Комментарий к ответу**

Прекрасно! А пока я **отвечу на ваш вопрос**.

Пояснительные  и однородные отношения для определений в определенных случаях могут **переходить в неоднородные,** между ними нет преграды.  Вот и здесь мы можем указать признаки как **поясняющие**, а можем объединить их **в одно сообщение**. Как выбрать?

Пусть по смыслу они будут **пояснительными в простом** предложении, и мы ставим запятую. А теперь переходим к **сложному** предложению.  Там важно обозначить **более крупный план** в семантике и интонации, и  такая "мелочь" нам уже неинтересна, а запятая **мешает.**

И еще. **Сравним два варианта.**

(1) *Он был в таком же как на мне, военном ватнике.* Это предложение воспринимается как **законченное**.

(2)  *Он был в таком же как на мне / военном ватнике…* Этому предложению, как я думаю, требуется **продолжение**.  Это можно заметить не только по интонации , но и по грамматике.

Comment: Сколько нюансов.)

Comment: Много, да...  Но вот поучительная история:  — Видите шишку? Будьте любезны, превратите её в лягушку. //  Отличник  поднёс флейту к губам и заиграл. Его толстые щёки вдохновенно раздувались. Через несколько секунд шишка зашевелилась, потом подпрыгнула, а спустя минуту выпустила зелёные лапы. // — Ну как? // — Вы подарили мне грандиозное разочарование в ваших скромных способностях! Это не лягушка!  Это жаба! Стыдитесь! Мастерство состоит именно в овладении нюансами. НЮАНС — это то, что правит миром.